# How to have multiple decorated arguments in controller methods like in NestJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, architecture, nestjs

I'm pretty interested in how NestJs has managed to create its controller. For example, I can do this in a NestJs controller.

```
@Controller('/mycontroller')
class MyController {

    @Post()
    createItemRoute(
      @Query() myQuery: myQueryDto,
      @Body() body: bodyDto,
      @Res() res: Response
      // I can add more parameters to here if I want or have a different set of parameters in another method
    ) {
      console.log('Query:', myQuery)
      console.log('Body:', body)
      console.log('Response:', res)
    }
}
```

I can basically add as many parameters as I want into the `createItemRoute`. The parameter are decorated and the eventual values in the parameters are all nicely processed by the decorated parameters for me to use.

Since NestJs uses Express, I assume that the `createItemRoute` was somehow passed in with the standard Express `req`, `res`, `next` parameters and then further passed into the decorated parameters for processing.

I'm curious about how this was done and decided to try replicating the same effect in an exercise but I couldn't figure out how to achieve it. Here's what I have so far:

```
function Post() {
    return function (target: Record<string, any>, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const original: Function = descriptor.value;

        // 1. To get the arguments of the original method
        const originalArguments = descriptor.value.arguments;  // But this causes an error that arguments cannot be used

        // 2. Changes the original method's signature to receive from Express just as an ordinary middleware function
        descriptor.value = function(req: Request, res: Response) { 
          const newArguments = []
          // 3. To loop through the arguments retrieved and apply them
          for (const param in originalArguments) {  // This fails too because I couldn't retrieve the arguments into originalArguments in the previous line
            newArguments.push(param(req, res))  // Somehow passes the req and res into the decorated arguments of the original method for them to process and return their processed values
          }
          originalMethod.apply(this, newArguments). // Then apply with the new arguments
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}

// 5. The @Body() decorator which returns a function so that it can be used in the Post() decorator
function Body() {
  return function (target: Record<string, any>, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    return (req, res) => {
      return res.body
    }
  }
}

const testMyController = new MyController();
const mockReq = { body: 'my body content' }
const mockRes = { status: (code) => true }
// 4. Assuming Express will pass its req and res into the function
testMyController.createItemRoute(mockReq, mockRes)  // This will cause Typescript to throw an error that the method signature mismatches the one created in MyController
```

In what I have tried, the idea was somehow to wrap the `createItemRoute` in `MyController` in another function through the decorator that can be used to receive parameters from Express. However, there are several problems which I have labelled them in my example code.

1. Since I can add as many parameters as I want into the controller method (`createItemRoute`), I need a way to retrieve the arguments in an array. The method isn't declared with `...args` and so I can't just get them directly. Using `descriptor.value.arguments` also throws an error that it isn't permitted. As much as I can, I wish to remain in strict mode.
2. I converted the original method's signature to fit the shape of a typical Express middleware so that I can later pass it as a middleware into Express. This didn't work as we will see later in Step #4.
3. As there are multiple decorated arguments passed into `createItemRoute`, I need to loop through them and provide each of them the raw `req` and `res` from Express so that the decorators can process them and return their values. However, there are several problems here.

   - First, the loop fails because I couldn't retrieve the arguments from the original method in the first place.
   - Second, I'm not sure how I can pass the `req` and `res` into the decorators. The part where I had `param(req, res)` doesn't seem to work too.
4. So, since I have converted the method signature of `createItemRoute` through the decorator, I thought I can start receiving the req and res values from Express. I mocked the `req` and `res`, and tried passing them into the `createItemRoute` method. But since I'm using Typescript, it will start to complain and throw errors about the mismatch in the method signature!
5. In the `@Body` decorator, I have planned to somehow receive the req and res from the `@Post` decorator in Step #3. But this obviously doesn't seem to work.

I need help to shed some light on how I can achieve the way controllers are able to made to work that way in NestJs.